# Alternate proof that continuous function on a compact set is bounded and attains a maximum

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

I have already proved that a continuous real-valued function maps compact sets into compact sets. So a continuous function on a compact set is bounded and attains maximum. I want to prove these facts the other way around.

---

Let $f: E\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $E$ is a compact metric space. Assume that $f$ is not bounded. Then for $n=1,2,\ldots$ there is a point $x_n\in E$ such that $|f(x_n)|>n$. Since $E$ is compact, the sequence $x_1,x_2,\ldots$ has a convergent subsequence $y_1,y_2,\ldots$. Contradiction with continuity of $f$, because $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (f(y_n)) = \infty$. Thus $f$ is bounded.

If $f$ is bounded, then there exists $L=\sup \{f(p) : p\in E \}$. Construct a sequence $f(z_1),f(z_2),\ldots $ convergent to $L$. Since $E$ is compact we can choose a convergent subsequence from $z_1,z_2,\ldots$. Let $a$ denote its limit. From continuity we have that $f(a)=\sup \{f(p) : p\in E \}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: The last two paragraphs are correct, if that is what you are asking. It is not clear what you mean by 'prove these facts the other way around'.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for misunderstanding. I just wanted to do another proof (the most common one is proving that continuous functions preserve compact sets). Also I have some doubts about the sentence "Construct a sequence $f(z_1),f(z_2),\ldots$... I believe that it is possible to choose such a sequence using definition of supremum (in every neighbourhood of a supremum there must be some other point).